# How to invalidate @Cachable cache when saveAndFlush throw an exception?

Tags: java, jpa

When I get a `GlobalData` instance with `get(Class<T> clazz)`, the `data` in the result entity is null.

After filtered out logs, I found there's a searize error that cause the line:`globalDataRepository.insert(data);`to throw a exception, but at the same time, the incorrect data has been cached by the mechanism of `@Cachable` in `DataModelRepository`.

The `get(Class<T> clazz)`

```
public <T extends GlobalPersistable> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
        int datatype = PersistableConverter.getDataType(clazz);
        GlobalData data = globalDataRepository.select(datatype);
        if (data == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if ((data = globalDataRepository.select(datatype)) == null) {
                    try {
                        data = new GlobalData<>();
                        data.setType(datatype);
                        data.setData(clazz.newInstance());
                        data = globalDataRepository.insert(data);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("", e);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (T) data.getData();
    }
```

The `GlobalData`:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "global_data")
public class GlobalData<T extends Persistable> implements DataModel<Integer> {

    @Id
    private int type;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMBLOB")
    @Convert(converter = PersistableConverter.class)
    private Persistable data;


    @Override
    public Integer getPK() {
        return type;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getData() {
        return (T) data;
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
public interface DataModelRepository<T extends DataModel<PK>, PK> extends AppRepository<T, PK> {
    String CACHE_NAME = "repository";

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_NAME, key = "#root.target.class.getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName() + '@' + #pk", unless = "#result==null")
    default T select(PK pk) {
        return findById(pk).orElse(null);
    }

    @CachePut(cacheNames = CACHE_NAME, key = "#root.target.class.getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName() + '@' + #entity.getPK()")
    default T insert(T entity) {
        return saveAndFlush(entity);
    }

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = CACHE_NAME, key = "#root.target.class.getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName() + '@' + #entity.getPK()")
    void delete(@Nonnull T entity);


}
```

How to delete the cache if `insert` throw a exception? Or cache the entity until the insert has finished correctly?

Comment: Don't use `@Cacheable` with JPA instead use 2nd level caching for your JPA provider. That way all the bad things that can happen and need cache invalidation is taken out of your hands and not something you have to keep yourself busy with. Not to mention that interesting things can and will happen especially as you have used `@Data` (for more info see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/).

Answer (score 0):

if the method throws an exception, you can catch it and call the cancel method.

This is the fast way I have in mind.
For example

```
public <T extends GlobalPersistable> method(String key) {
    try {
        return callMethodWithCacheable(key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        callMethodWithEvict(key);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Another way is to catch the exception inside the method that calls saveAndFlush and return an Either ([https://medium.com/disney-streaming/option-either-state-and-io-imperative-programming-in-a-functional-world-8e176049af81#:~:text=In%20theory%2C%20Either%20can%20represent,a%20failure%20of%20type%20A%20.](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/option-either-state-and-io-imperative-programming-in-a-functional-world-8e176049af81#:%7E:text=In%20theory%2C%20Either%20can%20represent,a%20failure%20of%20type%20A%20.)), if the Either contains the populated left position you call the delete method

For example

```
 public  <T extends GlobalPersistable> method(String key) {

    Either<Error, Success> successErrorEither = SafeExecution.exec(() -> callMethodWithCacheable(key));
    if (successErrorEither.isLeft()) {
        callMethodWithEvict(key);
        return null; //In this point for me is better return Optional
    } else {
        return successErrorEither.getRight();
    }

}
```